# How to Restrict access for a SharePoint Application to be accessed only within the server?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, central-administration, iis, access

How to Restrict access for a SharePoint Application(Central Admin) to be accessed only within the server but not accessed outside the server.

Comment: you want to restrict Central admin access only on server where it configured?

Comment: Yes if not only within the farm.